# How to make discord bot leave voice channel in python

Tags: python, discord

I made the code for the bot to join a voice channel here,

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith("join"):
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()

client.run("TOKEN")
```

I want the bot to leave the server that it is in when any user types "leave". How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [VoiceClient.disconnect()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.disconnect). Also, you'll need to create the voice client object and add the `get` import - `from discord.utils import get`

Try adding the following:

```py
    if message.content.startswith("leave"):
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        if client.user in channel.members:
            voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=message.guild)
            await voice.disconnect()
```